# sql server right join with condition returns rows that do not match condition

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I'm having problem with my right join. Below is my query;

```
select a.maintitle as TITLE,
       a.id AS ID,
       a.a_auto_produ AS HOUSENO,
       c.CARRIERGUID,
       substring(d.FILENAME,1,15),
       d.CARRIERGUID
  from a
         inner join c on a.id = substring(c.FILENAME,1,15)
                         and  c.CARRIERGUID='xxx'
         right join d on a.id = substring(d.FILENAME,1,15)
                         and d.CARRIERGUID='production'  -- <<< here
;
```

with the condition indicated. I expect to have `carrierguid` = Production returned. However the returned rows also contain `carrierguid` other than production as you may see below;

[image]

really appreciate any help on this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To elaborate a bit on sp_BlitzErik's comments above:

Your `RIGHT JOIN` says the following:

> I want all rows from `d`, with the data from any rows from the `a`-`c` join where `a.id = substring(d.FILENAME,1,15)` *and* `d.CARRIERGUID='production'`.

If `d.CARRIERGUID = 'production'`, then you still take the row from d - you just exclude any rows from the `a`-`c` `INNER JOIN` that might otherwise match.

If what you really meant was:

> I want all rows from `d` where `d.CARRIERGUID='production'`, with the data from any rows from the `a`-`c` join where `a.id = substring(d.FILENAME,1,15)`.

then you would need to take `d.CARRIERGUID='production'` out of the `RIGHT JOIN` `ON` clause, and make it the `WHERE` clause for the query as a whole.